# Caching a massive ordered collection

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm try to think of the best way to cache a very large collection (a couple million) that has a specific order using ehcache.

The objects in the collection are big (lots of properties). 
I'm looking for similar properties to a LinkedHashMap (O(1) lookup and order).

The order of the collection could change on any update of the objects.

I'm thinking of putting the ids of the object in some [sorted set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). But when I update the cache I have to make sure to synchronize this collection or use a [concurrent implementation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html). In the sorted set I would store both the id and what I need to sort on.

The cache of course would store the objects normally with the id being the key.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Now that I think about it I must just use my search engine (Solr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using Solr since we were already using it.